# OCR image cropping issue

Tags: android, ocr

I'm working on an android mobile application that uses Tesseract OCR to capture text using mobile phone camera. I got the application to capture an image and allow the user to crop it manually however, the OCR results that I'm getting are not accurate at all.

After cropping, the images appear to be stretched as well which I thought might be causing this issue. Is there a way I can improve the accuracy? I know I can apply image pre-processing, but in this case, I'm not loading the images from a file, I am directly capturing the text and getting the OCR results on my application. Is there a way I can process the image after cropping to achieve higher accuracy rate?

I have used this code for cropping

```
private void performCrop() {
try {
    //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(mImageCaptureUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 800);

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "/image.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.e("io", ex.getMessage());  
    }

    uri = Uri.fromFile(f);

  cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is stretched to weird proportions, Tesseract will give erroneous results, at least from previous experience. Haven't worked with it in a bit so things may have changed. OCR is dependent on geometric matching which is thrown off if scaling gets messed up. Fix that issue first.

Comment: The outputX and outputY values you are passing in your intent make the assumption the cropped area will be square which might not be the case.

Comment: Yes that's right, I usually crop the images in a rectangular shape.  Is there a better way to do the cropping?  keeping the quality of the image the same. 
Sorry, I'm new to all of this so I'm not sure how to fix it.